# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question recently:

[How does the design of a programming language relate to its name?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/how-does-the-design-of-a-programming-language-relate-to-its-name)

It now has a score of -2. It was closed because I asked two seperate questions, which have since been narrowed to one.

I don't feel my question has any content problems - I went and read through [the Meta question](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/are-questions-about-naming-a-programming-language-on-topic) that relates to questions about naming a programming language. My question isn't asking about what I should name something, it's asking about the impact of the design on the name of a programming language (which relates heavily to programming language design.)

Why isn't this question acceptable for this site?

Comment: I imagine the downvotes were given _before_ the edit, so they could be for the same reason it was originally closed.

Comment: Not really - one came straight after I made the edit.

Comment: I can't say in this case but in general folks with deep roots in *very* high question rate sites like Stack Overflow react quickly - often after reading only the title. I would have chosen "The evolution of the names C, C++ and maybe C# from the original B is easy to appreciate, but in general how (if at all) do the names of programming languages relate to their design?" Catch their eye with something informative and agreeable in the beginning. The "(if at all)" allows for "they don't" to be an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: Also, to avoid further down votes and close votes you should always add a short comment addressing the "I'm voting to close because" comment and state that it's been addressed. Some "fast responders" go directly from title to (the most negative of the) comments. That one has no response so their conclusion is that it's still true. You could also flag the comment for deletion with the reason "no longer needed". Lots of users leave their comments standing in perpetuity, even after they are no longer relevant and the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Relate" is a very vague word; there are zillions of ways that a thing can relate to another thing. I would say that almost any question with the word "relate" in the title can be clarified by being more specific in what kind of relation you're asking about.

The question body asks something slightly more specific: how the design would *"impact the chosen name"* of the language. This is more specific because it at least narrows it down to causal relationships where something about the design causes something about the name.

Nonetheless, that's still pretty broad, because there are many thousands of programming languages and each designer could have been thinking about different things when choosing a name; and we can't really know what motivated most of them, because most of them haven't said much in public about how they chose the name for their language. An answer could focus on a few languages where this is known, but it wouldn't be very representative; otherwise we can only speculate.

Another issue is that you're asking about how to name a *new* language, which is necessarily more opinion-based than if you were asking how *existing* languages' names have been chosen. The latter can be answered with facts and references.

---

That said, I think the question doesn't need to be changed that much to be improved. I would phrase it like this:

> ##### What do programming languages' names communicate about the languages?
>
> A language's name is typically the first thing people learn about it, so the name may be chosen to communicate something about the language in order to give the right first impression. What information, if any, have language designers tried to convey about their languages by their names?

I think this captures what you were looking for with your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll try and edit the question.